# AngularJS + FabricJS + ASP.MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, fabricjs

I create project asp.mvc and add angularjs and add fabricjs https://codepen.io/michaeljcalkins/pen/Imupw

Now I catch error in console: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: FabricProvider <- Fabric <- ExampleCtrl

My app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
angular.module('example', [
    'common.fabric',
    'common.fabric.utilities',
    'common.fabric.constants'
]).controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', 'Fabric', 'FabricConstants', 'Keypress', function ($scope, Fabric, FabricConstants, Keypress) {

    $scope.fabric = {};
    $scope.FabricConstants = FabricConstants;

    //
    // Creating Canvas Objects
    // ================================================================
    $scope.addShape = function (path) {
        $scope.fabric.addShape('http://fabricjs.com/assets/15.svg');
    };

    $scope.addImage = function (image) {
        $scope.fabric.addImage('http://stargate-sg1-solutions.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/daniel-season-nine.jpg');
    };

    $scope.addImageUpload = function (data) {
        var obj = angular.fromJson(data);
        $scope.addImage(obj.filename);
    };

    //
    // Editing Canvas Size
    // ================================================================
    $scope.selectCanvas = function () {
        $scope.canvasCopy = {
            width: $scope.fabric.canvasOriginalWidth,
            height: $scope.fabric.canvasOriginalHeight
        };
    };

    $scope.setCanvasSize = function () {
        $scope.fabric.setCanvasSize($scope.canvasCopy.width, $scope.canvasCopy.height);
        $scope.fabric.setDirty(true);
        delete $scope.canvasCopy;
    };

    //
    // Init
    // ================================================================
    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.fabric = new Fabric({
            JSONExportProperties: FabricConstants.JSONExportProperties,
            textDefaults: FabricConstants.textDefaults,
            shapeDefaults: FabricConstants.shapeDefaults,
            json: {}
        });
    };

    $scope.$on('canvas:created', $scope.init);

    Keypress.onSave(function () {
        $scope.updatePage();
    });
}]);
```

Find of "FabricProvider" in my Project has no result.

I load this project to https://github.com/HelenSPR/TestAngularjsFabricjs

Comment: have you added fabric.js in your .net mvc view before angular?

Comment: why are you using multiple module in your page `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);` this is never used in your code

Comment: Hi, I install angular first and then fabricjs. Now I remove this items and add first fabricjs and then angular. But this exception persists.

Comment: I load this project to https://github.com/HelenSPR/TestAngularjsFabricjs

Thanks a lot.

Comment: in your layout page you should include the bundle `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fabric" )` before the bundle `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularapp")` as app.js depends on the `Fabric` dependency from fabric.js which is included in the bundle `~/bundles/fabric`

Answer (score 0):

As per the code provided in github , in your _Layout.cshtml page you should include the script bundles like below order

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fabric" )
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularapp")
```

and you should remove the duplicate module and controller from the _Layout file as below

`<body ng-app="example" ng-controller= "ExampleCtrl">`

because you are using the same module and controller in index.cshtml also.

In your layout page you should include the bundle `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fabric" )` before the bundle `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularapp")` as `app.js` depends on the Fabric dependency from fabric.js which is included in the bundle `~/bundles/fabric`

Comment: Sorry, i have mistaike still.

Answer (score 0):

Niladri!
I restart VS and misteke take out!

**Thanks a lot of!!**